# Snowflake : Replace column value with text only if not null

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, Is there any function or easier way to Replace column value with text only if not null .

I have tried this, but not working as expected :

`SELECT IFF(x.Col1 != NULL, '****', NULL) FROM Table1 x`

Comment: do you want to replace all the non null values with one text?

Comment: != wont work for null. you can do this `SELECT IFF(x.Col1 is not NULL, '****', NULL) `

Comment: Please update your question with enough sample data to illustrate the possible scenarios and give the result you want to achieve for each one

Answer (score 0):

Using [NVL2](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nvl2):

```
SELECT NVL2(x.Col1, '****', NULL)
FROM Table1 AS x;
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE Table1(col1 TEXT) AS SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT 'abc';

SELECT x.Col1, NVL2(x.Col1, '****', NULL)
FROM Table1 AS x;
```

Output:

| COL1 | result |
| --- | --- |
| null | null |
| abc | **** |

---

EDIT:

> Is it possible to ignore NULL, empty and whitespace values also?

```
SELECT NVL2(TRIM(NULLIF(x.Col1, '')), '****', NULL)
FROM Table1 AS x;
```

Comment: Is it possible to ignore NULL, empty and whitespace values also?

Comment: @SrinivasanMK Yes, with TRIM/NULLIF, I have updated the answer

Comment: We have found a function that can able to match based on condition and replace it with given value for each case: 
DECODE(x.Col1, NULL, NULL, '*****')